# HttpClient.PostAsync fails if the ASP.NET server returns RedirectResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

On the server side I'm doing:

```
return Redirect(...); // <- doesn't matter which url
```

On client side I'm doing

```
await Http.PostAsync
```

It always gives an error..:

1- If I set it to "http://www.google.com" I get error:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure ---> System.Exception:    at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError(WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where)
```

2- If I set it to a relative url like "/", the await times out:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled
```

I've been stuck on this problem for a long time, I've finally found that it's all because for some reason HttpClient doesn't like being redirected apparently.

The exact some thing works perfectly fine when I test it in RESTClient in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Edit: Please ignore this question, it's a problem with Mono, complete simple code to reproduce here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42410/bug-httpclient-times-out-when-redirected-on-a-post-request

Comment: Post executable repro code.

Comment: @usr That would be really difficult

Comment: "If I set it to "http://www.google.com" I get error:" Can't you even repro connecting to Google? With the information present here right now I don't see how anyone can spot the problem. Also, the exception ToString would be nice.

Comment: @usr turns out the problem was in Mono, I'm running the code on Android using Xamarin (Mono). It works fine on desktop. If you are interested in that, I've posted complete simple code to reproduce here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42410/bug-httpclient-times-out-when-redirected-on-a-post-request